# How to get around angulars performance issue with large content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, data-binding

I'm familiar with angular's digest cycle and how it affects performance with long lists and large model values. I'm just curious if you have any workaround for the problem specifically for my case.
I'm building an app which may or may not require user to enter large text such as error log in the `textarea`, but due to angular inherent issue associated with 2-way data binding on **large model** its causing my app to hang.

Currently I'm asking users to attach large contents in a file. But I was wondering if there is any way at all to get around the issue.
One potential workaround I can think of is to not to use model on the text field and access the text using angular's lightweight jquery api `angular.element('#mytext').val()`. But this approach comes with disadvantage of closely binding JS code with DOM which is not a good practice. I'm interested in more "angular" style solution.

Here's the plunkr which demonstrates performance issue. To see the hang, start typing in the text area and you'll experience severe lag

http://plnkr.co/edit/0wccRJjjlhJqZtdipDLv?p=preview

[image]

Comment: Try to use a throttle function when user introduces the text.

Comment: Do you mean debounce? If so, i already have debounce of 1sec, it makes a slight difference not significant enough

Comment: throttle will allow you to execute the code when user finishes introducing chars after 1 sec. But debounce function is working too, but it will be executed each 1 second on text introduction.

Comment: Do you need the model to update on keyup, or can you limit it to only update on change? Look into ng-model-options: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bottleneck is not a digest (which would contribute but could be effectively fought with [`ngModelOptions` 'debounce' option](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions#usage)) but [a listener added by `textarea` directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.8/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1116) when `ng-model` is used on the element.

[image: Firebug profile]

This kind of performance issues suggests the usage of custom directive instead of built-in ones (`ngModel` in this case). For two-way binding it may be

```
app.directive('bigText', function () {
  return {
    scope: {
      bigText: '='
    },
    template: '<textarea>',
    link: function (scope, element) {
      // .val(value) on directive init
      var initialized = false;
      // prevents .val(oldValueFromOutside) on input
      var internalChange = false;
      var $textarea = element.find('textarea');

      scope.$watch('bigText', function (oldVal, newVal) {
        if (internalChange || (initialized && oldVal === newVal)) return;
        initialized = true;
        $textarea.val(newVal);
      });

      // generic JS debounce,
      // for ex. https://github.com/niksy/throttle-debounce
      var handler = debounce(1000, function () {
        var text = $textarea.val();
        if (scope.bigText !== text) {
          internalChange = true;
          scope.$apply(function () {
            scope.bigText = text;
          });
          internalChange = false;
        }
      });
      $textarea.on('change keyup', handler);
      // $textarea.off on scope destroy
    }
  };
});
```

The important part in maintaining two-way bindings manually is using `internalChange` flag, it prevents getting old value from outer scope as `newVal` on digest (chicken/egg dilemma).

Some things may also be learned from the treatment that Angular directives give to input events [for performance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.8/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1157) and [compatibility](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.8/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1164).

Notice that similar performance issues may be caused by [Chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=237433) and not by Angular application.